# Sync Safari tabs but not history between devices

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, safari, big-sur

How can I sync my Safari tabs between my iPhone 7 and my MacBook Pro without syncing the two browsers' history?

Comment: Do you mean other than iCloud Tabs or does that do something you don't want?

Comment: @fsb it doesn't seem to work for me at all.

Answer (score -1):

Please check out [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/666658/how-to-move-safari-tabs-between-iphone-ipad-and-mac/). It explains how to set up iCloud Tabs (So a way to access open tabs across all your Apple devices that have Handoff enabled. It's basically a way to open a tab on one Apple device that is currently open on an different Apple device)